# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir una fecha indicando nombres del día y mes?

Tags: java

Necesito mostrar la fecha actual del sistema con formato "Martes 07 de Febrero del 2017".

```
//obtengo la fecha actual
Date today = new Date();
lblFecha.setText(today);
```

Por ejemplo hoy es "Martes 07 de Febrero 2017" y mañana sería "Miércoles 08 de Febrero del 2017" y así conforme vayan pasando los dias, meses y años.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class JavaApplication4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Meses del anio
        String MES[] = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};

        // Dias de la semana
        String DIA[] = {"Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado"};

        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();

        String fecha = DIA[calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + " " + calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+ " de " + MES[calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + " del " + calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        lblFecha.setText(fecha);

    }

}
```

### Actualizacion

**Debido a comentarios realizados por otros usuarios de la comunidad, respecto a la solucion y su rendimiento, he aqui una solucion que tambien puede servir para tu pregunta.**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class JavaApplication4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de' MMMM 'del' YYYY").format(new Date());

        System.out.println(fecha);

    }

}
```

Resultado:

> martes 07 de febrero del 2017

La clase `SimpleDateFormat` recibe como parametro constructor un formato de fecha, cuya sintaxis puedes validar [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), este nos retorna una cadena (String), la cual podra ser pasada al JLabel. Ten en cuenta entonces los siguientes elementos respecto a la cadena del formato.

Los `'` permiten *escapar* un texto dentro del formato, con lo cual se podra cambiar el `de`/`del`, para organizarlo como desees.

Comment: Es mas util usar un arreglo con los Dias de la Semana y los meses del año en español, ya que estos pueden variar dependiendo de la configuracion regional del ordenador

Comment: Entiendo que si alguien tiene la configuración del ordenador en otro idioma, es por que utiliza ese idioma

Comment: Pero además, puedes establecer el idioma mediante el argumento locale. Me parece absurdo tener que crear los arreglos que indicas para algo que ya está hecho.

Comment: Puedes usar `SimpleDateFormat` y `Locale`, con eso te facilita mucho más que estar creando tu propia implementación.

Comment: No seria mas util, comentar esto con la persona que hizo la pregunta? Y que en ese caso el seleccione la que mas se ajuste a su caso, yo aplique la solucion basado en lo que el requeria y tambien basado en que crei que podria ser una solucion apropiada a su problema, en lugar de estar discutiendo...Creeria yo

Comment: Lo comento contigo porque brindas una respuesta. Para mí, la respuesta debe brindar todo lo necesario para resolver la pregunta **bien**. Lo que veo aquí, es que la resuelve, pero no **bien**. Por ello, voto en contra.

Comment: La he editado, agregando entonces la aclaracion respecto a los comentarios de otras respuestas. Espero os guste.

Comment: En mi opinion ahora si resuelve un poco mejor el problema.

Comment: Está mejor. Te recomiendo aumentarle el `Locale` para asegurar que esté en español. Eso funcionará bien en tu equipo, en el mío no muestra ese resultado porque la región está configurada en inglés/Estados Unidos. Mejor aún, mira la respuesta de @Dani.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
lblFecha.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de' MMMM 'de' YYYY").format(new java.util.Date()))
```

Si necesitas fijar un idioma predeterminado que no sea el del sistema operativo puedes hacerlo mediante:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de' MMMM 'de' YYYY", Locale.UK)
```

Answer (score 1):

Desde JAVA 8 puedes hacer uso de las nuevas Clases para manipular Fechas y Horas en el package java.time.*

```
    String MES[] = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
    String DIA[] = {"Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado"};

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    lblFecha.setText(DIA[date.getDayOfWeek().getValue()] + " " + date.getDayOfMonth() + " "+MES[date.getMonthValue()-1]+" del " + date.getYear());
```

Comment: También puedes usar un `Locale` para no tener que usar tus términos en español, Java lo puede proveer.

Comment: me puedes ayudar con un ejemplo ?

Comment: `LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy", new Locale("es", "PE")); System.out.println(date.format(formatter));`